# VS2017 nuget keeps searching for packages in wrong location

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, packagereference

So I migrated from nuget packages.config to PackageReference and found out there were some compatibility issues. I reverted the project to its working state (before the PackageReference) and now my project is not compiling.

I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       The package EntityFramework with version 6.2.0 could not be found in C:\Users\user.nuget\packages. Run a NuGet package restore to download the package.   DbManager

This happened to multiple packages. It seems that Nuget is searching for packages in the user.net\package directory for some reason. Originally, there was a folder within the project that contained all the packages.

I forced the global path to be at the folder within the project by editing the NuGet.Config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\Projects\App\App Source\packages\" />
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="C:\Projects\App\App Source\packages\" />
  </config>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
</configuration>
```

I don't know why Nuget keeps looking for packages at that location. It should be looking at the packages folder within the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="EntityFramework6.Npgsql" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Npgsql" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6" version="1.7.17" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

All of these packages in packages.config are not being found. This problem started happening when I tried PackageReference.

Is there any way to reset Nuget's settings? I would appreciate any guidance in solving this problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue and resolved it by clearing the NuGet caches (VS => Tools => Options =>NuGet Package Manager => Clear Caches)

Comment: Tried that. Did not change anything. It keeps looking for packages at the default nuget global path (under users)... I'm considering doing a clean install but I'm not sure which is the problem: my local project, Nuget, or Visual Studios

Comment: Did you ever solve this. I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 12):

**TLDR; This is caused by latent copies of the new `project.assets.json` file being left in your `/obj/` folders.  These can be safely deleted.**

You can run this Powershell (at your own risk) in your root solution folder as a quick way to purge these files:

```
ls project.assets.json -Recurse | foreach {rm $_}
```

`project.assets.json` is generated for projects using `PackageReference` to cache the Nuget dependency graph for your project.  It seems to confuse Visual Studio/Nuget if it's left there even if your project is using (or reverted back to using) `packages.config`

This can happen in Visual Studio 2019 as well, if you try `PackageReference` and then revert back to `packages.config` (or even if you switch between Git branches with one Nuget restore method versus the other).

**Further Info**
More info on `project.assets.json` here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x